# Change the name of toggle button in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a button should have "Start" as value then if the button clicked 
should change to "Pause"

```
> <script> let isOn = false;

    fucntion startPause() {

       if (!isOn){
         // do something
         isOn = true;    }else{
          // do something else
        isOn = false; }

    // ... </script>



    <button data-bind ="click: startPause" ></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example :
https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/70/

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="text:buttonText,click:startPause">
```

**JS:**

```
 function AppViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.buttonText = ko.observable('Start');
        self.startPause = function (){
           // here you can have your own logic to toggle the value
        self.buttonText(self.buttonText().toUpperCase() === 'START' ? 'Pause' : 'Start');
      }
    }
 ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the text binding and use an observable to change it's value on the model.

ref: [The "text" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html)